# Перевод формата даты "PHP"

Tags: дата

У меня есть такая строка - текущая дата + 7 дней:
 $nextweek  = date(mktime(date("m")  , date("d")+7, date("Y")));

Нужно перевести результат в вид '2016-02-19'
Как это сделать?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php вы бы свой date первым параметром прямо маску задали по которой выдать

Comment: Делал так:
$nextweek  = date("Y-m-d",mktime(date("m")  , date("d")+7, date("Y")));
Выводит в нужном формате, но показывает текущий день т.е. 12 число, а нужно 19ое

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mktime.php первыми 3 аргументами берет часы минуты и секунды, а потом уже месяц день год, так что mktime(0,0,0,date("m") , date("d")+7, date("Y"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Текущую дату +7 дней короче получать так:

```
date("Y-m-d",time()+7*24*60*60);
```

С помощью [mktime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mktime.php) так:

```
date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,date("m") , date("d")+7, date("Y")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Первым параметром задаете формат, вторым вашу дату. `date('Y-m-d', $date);`